# How can I link Trac with Git?

Tags: git, trac

I am trying to set up Trac 1.0.1 with git on CentOS 7.
Trac is running fine but I am not able to link a Git repository with Trac.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
yum install git
adduser git
mkdir -p /srv/git/myrepo
cd /srv/git/myrepo
git --bare --shared=true init
chown -R git:git -R /srv/git/myrepo
```

At this point I am able to clone and checkin changes from a client.
Now I want to browse the source files via trac. Here I've changed the Trac.ini like this:

```
repository_type = git
[components] 
tracopt.versioncontrol.git.* = enabled
```

If I understand correctly, I now have two options to add the repository.

- Directly in the Trac.ini file

  ```
  repository_dir = /srv/git/myrepo
  ```
- or via the admin panel in the menu 'repositories'

If I add the repo directly in the trac.ini config-file I get the following error:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)"
>   (`/srv/git/myrepo` does not appear to be a Git repository.). Look in the
>   Trac log for more information.

The problem here is, that there is no log file, although it's set in the `trac.ini` to debug and to `trac.log`. If I add the repo via the admin panel, I get no errors but there is also no browse tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose that you run the _git init_ command into /srv/git/myrepo, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here again,
the problem was SELinux.

`chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t /srv/git` fixed the problem.

More information about Trac and SELinux: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWithSeLinux

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `.git` to the `repository_dir`: `repository_dir = /srv/git/myrepo`. The issue has been fixed in [#11297](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11297) for the forthcoming Trac 1.0.2. I also recommend against using the `[trac]` `repository_dir` option since it is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release of Trac [#11703](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11703). You can configure your repositories in the database through the repository admin page or through the `[repositories]` section of trac.ini. See the [TracRepositoryAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin) documentation for more information.

Please post your `[logging]` section settings if you continue to have trouble getting the logging to work. Keep in mind you need `log_type` set to `file`. The easiest way is to just set it from the admin panel.

Comment: The `.git` is not needed for a bare repository. More discussion on the [trac-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/CN7bBUSJSVw/mGgvF13xOKMJ).

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with this. There's no `[components]` section in the initial Trac.ini, and several different methods for enabling and adding repositories to your Trac environment are presented, leading one to believe that any *one* of them will suffice. I believe this not to be the case.

The successful actions for me were to:

- Specify the following in the TracIni `[versioncontrol]` section:
  `default_repository_type = 'git'`
- Add the missing `[components]` section to trac.ini:

  ```
  [components]
  tracopt.versioncontrol.git.* = enabled
  ```
- Use the 'database' method and `trac-admin` to add the repository. Please note: 'git' is not yet "a valid type". Omit this final argument to the command:

  `repository add <repo> <dir> [type]`

Comment: [Markdown note] You *can* in fact nest code blocks (and even whole paragraphs) inside a list. It just requires some extra indentation; sometimes 2 or 4 extra spaces.

Comment: Cool. I struggled a bit with it.